# py2exe generating large file

Tags: python, user-interface, py2exe

For my practice, I created a simple GUI application with wxPython. I have compiled it with py2exe. But the problem is, the total size is 19.6 MB. I don't have any idea how to generate small files with py2exe, I know there are some ways to do that. Like using the `options` and `includes/excludes`. I used that but that came to no help, maybe I didn't know how to use them properly.

**However, the size-eaters are actually the dll files (they take about 6/7 mb)**. If you want to know what the program does, well, it can be called only a **SKELETON** of a program which does nothing in particular, just a GUI design. It has got some buttons, a filemenu, few textctrls etc. If you need to examine my code, please look here: http://pastebin.com/nfgHZHxg

Comment: You can try deleting some DLLs and see if the program still works, then figure out how to let the DLLs not get included in the first place. But in general 20 MB for a GUI application is not large by my book.

Comment: I have tried deleting the dll, every one of them is needed. The program doesn't work if you delete even single one. And you're talking 20MB is not much? This guy was able to make a 6 mb gui program: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617868/how-to-reduce-size-of-exe-using-py2exe, and again, my program is only a skeleton, actually it does nothing. Please go to my code link, paste it in a file and run the program if you want.

Comment: What version of python, and of wx?  What's your setup script look like?  Are you checking the size of the entire dist directory, or of an archive file?  There's not much we can help you with without knowing what you've tried.

Comment: I use py2exe through gui2exe which put many unnecessary stuff in exclude option by default. Also, you can use http://upx.sourceforge.net/ on the executable created by py2exe to further reduce the size. But, 19.6 MB sounds not too bad to me either.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I am using python 2.7.3 and wxpython 3.0. My setup script is simple with NO extra `options` parameter. I don't use `options` parameter because I don't know how to use that properly. I am taking about entire `dist` directory, there only resides files with only one projects, I always clear out the `dist` directory before creating new executables.

Comment: @otterb Well, I searched about UPX but I don't have any clear understanding about that. What does it do in my files, and how to use it?

Comment: upx compresses dll and exe. you use it after py2exe created exe pyd, dll etc. Check http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/BetterCompression. Try gui2exe https://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/ as GUI interface to py2exe then you dont have to learn much about py2exe parameter options.

Comment: @otterb I used GUI2Exe. But when I run the program, it says, 'msvcr90.dll' not found. Python version is 2.7.3 and I already have Visual C++ 2008. Yet I went to py2exe website and installed the visual c++ from the given link. But the problem still persists. Also downloaded the dll seperately and placed it in required locations, but no luck.

Comment: I just search for msvcr90.dll in C:\Windows and copy it to the same folder as the python source script. Then, py2exe automatically finds and packages it. It works for me either from py2exe alone or from gui2exe. Do you have a right version of dll?

Comment: @otterb I use GUI2EXE. How do you do that there? For me, I copied the file to where the python main script resided. It didn't work. Added the dll in the DATA FILE section, it still didn't work. Oh, I must mention that when I have the dll file in C:\Windows\System32 (Though I have Viusal C++ installed, the dll never existed there, I downloaded the dll and pasted it. I reinstalled Visual C++ but no luck), it shows: "Runtime Error! ..... An application made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly....."

Comment: This is odd... GUI2EXE will miss msvc unless I copy it to the source folder. BTW, I have version 9.00.21022.8 of msvcp90.dll. If this is not copied automatically, you can manually copy it along side the exe created (not in subfolders). VS2008 express should be the right version as in (http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/). So, I don't know why you still have a problem. Runtime error is really about msvc? or wxpython3.0? I never packaged 3.0 but lot of times with wxpython 2.8.